# EJB/JPA: constraint and idempotency violation

Tags: sql, jpa, orm, ejb, one-to-many

I'm working on a web portal for a recreational badminton leauge (register and analyze game statistics).Yesterday, when I started to implement a view showing team statistics (e.g. played/won/lost games...), I found a mysterious bug.

When I retrieve all teams with a query, the field which is supposed to contain the game series played away from home also includes the series played on home court. The field containing the series played on home court does however not contain the series played away from home (which is the behaviour I want).

Furthermore, If I execute the query again (update the page), the field containing the game series played away from home start growing. Each time I execute the query the set of home games are registered once again in the awaySeries field.

For instance:

**first query:**

*Team1*

gameSeriesAway: Team1 vs Team2, *Team1 vs Team3*

gameSeriesHome: Team1 vs Team3

**second query:**

*Team1*

gameSeriesAway: Team1 vs Team2, *Team1 vs Team3*, *Team1 vs Team3*

gameSeriesHome: Team1 vs Team3

**Team.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Team.findAll", query="SELECT distinct t FROM Team t")})
public class Team implements Comparable<Team> {

    public static final String FIND_ALL_TEAMS = "Team.findAll";
    //Fields
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String description;

    //Relationships
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Division> divisionHistory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="homeTeam")
    private List<GameSeries> homeSeries;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="awayTeam")
    private List<GameSeries> awaySeries;

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Team)
            return name.equals(((Team) obj).name)? true:false;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**GameSeries.java**

```
@Entity
public class GameSeries {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 5;

    // Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp playDate;

    // Relationships
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "series")
    private List<Game> games;

    @ManyToOne
    private Division division;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team homeTeam;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team awayTeam;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof GameSeries)
            return playDate.equals(((GameSeries) obj).playDate)
                && homeTeam.equals(((GameSeries) obj).homeTeam)
                && awayTeam.equals(((GameSeries) obj).awayTeam) 
                ? true : false;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return  playDate.hashCode() + 2*homeTeam.hashCode() + awayTeam.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The corresponding tables look like this:

**GameSeries**

---

id                PRIM

playDate

awayTeam_name     MUL

division_id       MUL

homeTeam_name     MUL

---

**Team**

---

name              PRIM

descripion

---

I have a hunch that this is a very simple problem to solve, but since I'm new to JPA/EJB I just can't figure this one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the code line by line, it seems that I found the error.

In my statistics utility class I joined the awayGameSeries and homeGameSeries into a single List:

```
List<GameSeries> allSeries = new ArrayList<GameSeries>(team.getAwaySeries());
allSeries.addAll(team.getHomeSeries());

... compute statistics for all game series
```

The **new ArrayList(argument)** "points" to the original awayGameSeries, and adding an object to the new list therefore appends the awayGameSeries as well. (I.e. When the line **addAll(team.getHomeSeries());** is executed, the homeGameSeries are added to the awayGameSeries)

To solve this, just add one line of code:

```
List<GameSeries> allSeries = new ArrayList<GameSeries>();
allSeries.addAll(team.getAwayGameSeries());
allSeries.addAll(team.getHomeSeries());
```